# Alternative to if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I need to find an alternative way for this `(if else statement)` :

---

```
    if(representatives.indexOf(word) == -1){  
        representatives.add(word);    

    }
    else if(repeatWords.indexOf(word) == -1){  
        repeatWords.add(word); }
```

Comment: its sound ok. there are different list managed for both the conditions. There are no any similarity of among them.

Comment: You could use `contains` instead of `indexOf`, but otherwise, this is just fine.

Comment: @bmt is there any easy way than using indexOf(word) ?

Comment: @ David Wallace I am beginner so I don't know what .indexOf(word) == -1) mean I want something easy

Comment: @rose, as david explained for list there is `contains`. you can go for it.

Comment: @bmt it is not working do you have any other idea

Comment: any error!!  what is `word` variable type? what is type of `representatives`? is it list?

Comment: If you don't know what the methods do, read the documentation for them.

Comment: Change representatives and repeatWords to `Set`. Then you can just `add(word)` without `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with contains as devid explained. `contains` is a function of list to checkout object contains or not. so you have to modify code like below:

```
 if(!representatives.contains(word)){  
        representatives.add(word);    

    }
    else if(!repeatWords.contains(word)){  
        repeatWords.add(word); }
```

It check if list don't contain object then add it. otherwise; everything seems ok!!.